# Uploading big size file on server?

Tags: java, file-upload

I need to  upload the files on server. It can be done either thru webservice/or UI. I just need to store that file content in DB. 
File can be of any size  upto 2 to 4 GB as well. I am not sure whats the way to upload big size file on server without
getting out of memory exception?

System Configuration :- 8 GB ,java 7 64 bit processor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am not sure whats the way to upload big size file on server without getting out of memory exception?

That part is easy.  Don't buffer the entire file in memory.  Stream it straight to disk.

(Pseudo code ... ignoring exception handling and resource management)

```
InputStream in = ...
OutputStrean out = ... // the place you want to ultimately store the file

byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}

// close streams.
```

**UPDATE**

You seem to be confused about how to get the input stream.

- If you are using the Servlet APIs, then use you can get the request's input stream using [`ServletRequest.getInputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getInputStream%28%29).
- If you are using different APIs, be specific ... and I'll look into it for you.

---

The more difficult part is dealing with the various issues to do with uploaded file encoding, encapsulation and so on.  For that, the best approach is to look for an existing solution.  But that depends on the context in which you are doing the uploads; e.g. what web container you are using, etc.

Here's an example: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/

Comment: As file upload request from httprequest which will contain the complete file content.So i don't have the option to partially read it. Am i missing something here?. Your point is valid when i am reading the content from file under disk and i have option to tell inputstream how much to load in one step. But what about scenario when client from UI/webservice uploading the complete file in single go under request ?

Comment: You are missing practically everything he said. Just read the file and write it to the output stream of a URLConnection, exactly as shown here. You should also enable chunked transfer mode.

Comment: @Stephen C. I am extremely sorry. But still i have doubt. Here is my doubt. When somebody from UI uploads the 4 GB file, as soon as request(ServletRequest) comes to server containing 4 GB of data. Won't my server get out of memory ? ServletRequest.getInputStream() just retrieves the body of the request as binary data using a ServletInputStream. But when request itself is so heavy, wont my server go out of memory .

Comment: @user3198603 - You are incorrect.  If you stream the data, you won't get an OutOfMemoryError.  `ServletRequst.getInputStream()` does not load the entire request body into memory.  It gives you a stream that reads the body from the socket.  Sure there will be some buffering, but I wouldn't expect it to be more than 100k bytes.

Comment: Thanks Stephen C. Looks like i am going to learn thing here. Now i start getting it. You mean to say that when i get servletRequest in my servlet, request object does not contain the data in itself
but data actually in under socket(which probably is hardware and can contain any amount of data). When i do ServletRequst.getInputStream(),
it gives us the stream that reads the body from the socket. Is that correct ?

Comment: If yes is it true for request.getParameter() also whether it is post or get request? I believe its for get request, request itself contains the data while for post request data is on socket.

Comment: @user3198603 - In answer to your questions.  1) It is pretty much correct that the stream returned by getInputStream reads from the body data from the socket.  2) getParameter gets parameters from either the request URL or from POST data; see the javadocs: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)